# Why wouldn't a comment saying ~"avoid travel during COVID" be deleted after flagging it?

Tags: discussion, comments, flagging

I flagged a comment for deletion. The comment is essentially stating ~"avoid travel during COVID". Full comment (that was the first comment added on the question):

> Maybe you should just be sensible and NOT travel at the moment, even when it is not really forbidden. All government publications about travel in COVID 19 times ask to do only needed travel or even not to travel at all. So please only travel if it is essential. We all miss going places, if all people keep to the restrictions now we will be out of COVID faster and can all travel again.

This comment doesn't address the question it was posted on, could be added on most questions on this website since ~March 2020, and most people are already aware of it (though it certainly doesn't apply to all government publications: some governments do encourage traveling for leisure).

Why wasn't the comment deleted?

If we wish to give such pandemic warnings, then see [Can we have a big fat DO NOT TRAVEL FOR FUN RIGHT NOW banner?](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6522/1810) and let's not clutter the comment sections, which are made to address the questions.

Comment: The comment still has value, in my view and in that of a fellow mod. And it got support of other users. So after discussing it, we decided to leave it for a few more days.

Comment: I'd be curious to see the comment. Where is the comment?

Comment: @unforgettableidSupportsMonica https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/159582/1810

Comment: @Willeke What's the value?

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt decline re-flagging of the comment today, because as you pointed out, there's this meta post.  Let's not double up.   Also not my comment, not my discussion, but after a quick glance they've made a judgement call. Do we really need to overanalyse every single comment, especially what appears to be a relatively benign (inoffensive) one?

Comment: @MarkMayo I just don't see the point of a comment essentially saying don't travel on a travel website.

Comment: again, not my comment, but it doesn't say don't travel. It suggests avoiding non-essential travel, according to govt's recommendations.  What's the value of saying govts spend 10x more on military than medicine? I'd be happier just removing the whole comments thread as there's literally a conversation going on, when the site rules say comments aren't for extended discussion :/  But anyway, I'll leave it to Willeke

Comment: @MarkMayo "avoiding non-essential travel, according to govt's recommendations" can apply to pretty much all the thousands of questions posted since people realized COVID-19 was contagious. That shouldn't be a comment since it isn't at all specific to the question, but instead a website  banner if we think people here aren't aware of it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When I wrote that comment I could see from a series of questions that you were planning a trip to Mexico, using loopholes in the laws and COVID 19 rules, not breaking the law but certainly not acting as a responsible adult in my view.

It seems from later posts that you have indeed reached Mexico.

The difference with most recent questions on the site is that those are usually about needed travel or about getting back home or to visit people while keeping to the letter as well as the spirit of the laws and rules.  Not travel for the fun of it.

From other reactions I could see more people hoped you be sensible.

An extra point, mods do not have to delete every post that is flagged and there is a certain leeway in what is allowed in comments, I did not agree with your reasons to delete the comments but will move them to a chatroom when I next have time.